# python 3: mock a method of the boto3 S3 client

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, boto3, botocore

I want to unit test some code that calls a method of the `boto3` `s3` client. 
I can't use `moto` because this particular method (`put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration`) is not yet implemented in `moto`. 
I want to mock the S3 client and assure that this method was called with specific parameters.

The code I want to test looks something like this:

```python
# sut.py
import boto3

class S3Bucket(object):
    def __init__(self, name, lifecycle_config):
        self.name = name
        self.lifecycle_config = lifecycle_config

    def create(self):
        client = boto3.client("s3") 
        client.create_bucket(Bucket=self.name)
        rules = # some code that computes rules from self.lifecycle_config
        # I want to test that `rules` is correct in the following call:
        client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(Bucket=self.name, \
          LifecycleConfiguration={"Rules": rules})

def create_a_bucket(name):
    lifecycle_policy = # a dict with a bunch of key/value pairs
    bucket = S3Bucket(name, lifecycle_policy)
    bucket.create()
    return bucket
```

In my test, I'd like to call `create_a_bucket()` (though instantiating an `S3Bucket` directly is also an option) and make sure that the call to `put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration` was made with the correct parameters.

I have messed around with `unittest.mock` and `botocore.stub.Stubber` but have not managed to crack this. Unless otherwise urged, I am not posting my attempts since they have not been successful so far.

I am open to suggestions on restructuring the code I'm trying to test in order to make it easier to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the test to work with the following, where `...` is the remainder of the arguments that are expected to be passed to `s3.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration()`.

```python
# test.py
from unittest.mock import patch
import unittest

import sut

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("sut.boto3")
    def test_lifecycle_config(self, cli):
        s3 = cli.client.return_value
        sut.create_a_bucket("foo")
        s3.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration.assert_called_once_with(Bucket="foo", ...)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: thanks this comment helped me getting boto3 to mock with @patch